# Go - Fail to download from s3 using s3manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm using the script from this post to download files from s3.
Everything works fine except the downloaded files are all 0B.

My script are basically the same as the script above.
I use `~/.aws/credentials` to set my keys and set region in the script.

Here is my script:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
)

var (
    Bucket         = "logs" // Download from this bucket
    Prefix         = "local-dir/my_log/20150611/20150611"    // Using this key prefix
    LocalDirectory = "s3logs"   // Into this directory
)

func main() {
    manager := s3manager.NewDownloader(nil)
    d := downloader{bucket: Bucket, dir: LocalDirectory, Downloader: manager}

    client := s3.New(&aws.Config{Region: "ap-northeast-1"})
    params := &s3.ListObjectsInput{Bucket: &Bucket, Prefix: &Prefix}
    client.ListObjectsPages(params, d.eachPage)
}

type downloader struct {
    *s3manager.Downloader
    bucket, dir string
}

func (d *downloader) eachPage(page *s3.ListObjectsOutput, more bool) bool {
    for _, obj := range page.Contents {
        d.downloadToFile(*obj.Key)
    }

    return true
}

func (d *downloader) downloadToFile(key string) {
    // Create the directories in the path
    file := filepath.Join(d.dir, key)

    if err := os.MkdirAll(filepath.Dir(file), 0775); err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Downloading " + key)
    // Setup the local file
    fd, err := os.Create(file)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer fd.Close()

    // Download the file using the AWS SDK
    fmt.Printf("Downloading s3://%s/%s to %s...\n", d.bucket, key, file)
    params := &s3.GetObjectInput{Bucket: &d.bucket, Key: &key}
    d.Download(fd, params)
}
```

The script listed the objects in the bucket very well, but did not download files into my local file system. And the script did not run into any exception.

Any idea why?
Thanks!

Comment: You're not checking the error return value from `d.Download(fd, params)`. Does it return something?

Comment: @jcbwlkr You are right! It turns out that `d.Download(fd, params)` return an error indicating that there is no region setting in my s3manager. I managed that by `manager := s3manager.NewDownloader(&s3manager.DownloadOptions{S3: client})`, of which client is already set with a region. Thank you very much!